# Jquery : Call of anonymous function doesn't work in submit()

Tags: jquery, forms, function, submit, anonymous

I'm having trouble with the submit() function.
I need to submit a form after checking a checkbox, so I have a form in which I have a checkbox.

So when I do this, it's working :

```
$(function() {
    $("#myCheckbox").change(function() { 
        $(this).parentsUntil("#feuilles_form").parent().submit();
    });
});
```

But it's not working anymore when I'm trying something like this :

```
$(function() {
    $("#myCheckbox").change(function() { 
        $(this).parentsUntil("#feuilles_form").parent().submit(function() {
            .....
        });
    });
});
```

And I get no log from my console or firebug...
I need to do this cause I'll have to use Ajax for the next step : refresh a div on my page.

Do you have any solution ?

Thx in advance !

Seb

Comment: If you pass a function as an argument to `submit()`, a new `submit` evend is bound. No `submit` event will be triggered.

Comment: is there more then one form on the page?  can you attach that function to the submit of the form in the document ready instead of the checkbox change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `.submit(function(){})` you are registering a function to call when the submit occurs.

Try this:

```
$(this).parentsUntil("#feuilles_form").parent().submit(function() {
}).submit();
```

Since you mention ajax, registering the anonymous function in the change event *might* cause multiple anonymous functions registered to the submit handler. **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/W6dEp/)**

It will most likely always be better to register the `.submit()` once during dom ready.

```
$(function() {
    var $form = $("form");
    $form.submit(function() {
        $("form").append("<h1>submited</h1>");
        return false;
    });

    $(":checkbox").change(function() {
        $form.submit();
    });
});
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/W6dEp/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

As written, the second example only `binds` your anonymous function to the submit event. You still need to trigger it; e.g.

```
    $(this).parentsUntil("#feuilles_form").parent().submit(function() {
        .....
    }).submit();
```

Comment: Thanks also for the explanation, I'll know it for my future projects ;)

Answer (score 1):

As [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) will explain, calling a function like `submit` with *no arguments* is analogous to calling `trigger`, which is why the first works. If you pass arguments, it's like calling `bind`, which only sets event handlers, but doesn't fire the event.

Solution: do both. Why not just execute the contents of your function after the submit call, since you're the one triggering it anyway? Does it need to be a handler?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I'll know it now :)